# Insert text in RichTextEditor on cursor position

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'd to insert date on a richtexteditor when the user click on a button.
This part is easy, more difficult, how to insert this on cursor position. Cursor position may be on the beginning, middle or end of the text.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
    protected function richText_keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == 66) //or remove if statement
            richText.insertText("Really?");
    }


    <s:RichEditableText id="richText" text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"   
keyDown="richText_keyDownHandler(event)"/>
```

**EDIT:** for mx `RichTextEditor`

```
        protected function richText_keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            var ind:int = richEdit.selection.beginIndex;
            richEdit.text = richEdit.text.substring(0, ind) +   
            "Your text variable here" +   
            richEdit.text.substring(ind, richEdit.text.length);     
        }
```

and mx rich text editor:

```
    <mx:RichTextEditor id="richEdit" text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"  
 keyDown="richText_keyDownHandler(event)"/>
```

Maybe there is more effective method, but this is the only I could think of.

Comment: Thanks but with <mx:RichTextEditor insertText is not availible

Comment: One problem with this approach. If the user has done any formatting, in the editor (like make the text bold or italic), after this event, that formatting goes away. Does anyone know how to overcome that issue?